# Backbone.js - "Object [object Object] has no method 'listenTo'"

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Question: I have code that works like this:
BottomPaneView

```
initialize: function() {
  ...
  this.childView = null
  ...
  this.listenTo(this.childView, "findUnit", this.findUnit);
}
```

in another function,

```
{
  ...
  this.childView = new TrackingView(...);
  this.childView.render()
  ...
}
```

The last line in initialize throws "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listenTo' ". Doesn't this refer to a View object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was I was using v0.9.0, and backbone didn't implement listenTo until 0.9.9. I updated to v1.0.0 and everything worked.

Note that before this, I moved the problem line below the `this.childView.render()` in the second function to make sure the argument was initialized. I don't know if what I was doing initially would have worked.

Answer (score 1):

The `this.childView` must be an instance of `Backbone.View`. Do a `console.log` before the binding statement to check this.